# How do I remove the Gluon controls from Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

How do I remove the Gluon controls from Scene Builder?

We tend to use the search bar to find controls, and Gluon has a number of their own controls that have names that overlap with those in the standard library (TextField, ProgressBar, and ProgressIndicator), in addition to clashing with some of our own custom control names. This often results in folks adding the wrong control to a scene and wasting time trying debugging.

The Library Manager is empty. There is nothing in the Library folder under Custom Library Folder -> Reveal in Explorer. I am not sure where else to look, or even if it's possible to remove them. Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure you can; they look to be built-in to the application just like the standard JavaFX objects (Gluon maintains Scene Builder).

Answer (score 2):

Hi，I find a way to solve your problem. You just start to use gluon theme when you set gluon. So you just need to change the theme which can be selected in SceneBuilder **menubar->Preview->Themes** and select **Modena** which is the default theme.